# Exponential Regression Line in R

Tags: r, plot, line, regression, exponential

I was plotting some data and was trying to plot exponential regression line through the data points. I have done quite a bit research on how to do that, and finally came across an instruction that I could understand and perform. However, when I continued to use the same method for other plots, the regression line did not seem to fit the data points. I could not figure out why. Can i get some help please?

[This](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-tutorial-5/) link is where i found the instruction.

Below are my codes and results:

```
exponential.model <- lm(A~log(B), AB)
bvalues <- seq(0,180,0.1)
exponential <- predict(exponential.model, list(B = bvalues))
plot(A~B, AB, log="y")
lines(bvalues, exponential, lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

[image: Plot AB]

```
exponential.model <- lm(C~log(D), CD)
dvalues <- seq(0,1380,0.1)
exponential <- predict(exponential.model, list(D = dvalues))
plot(C~D, CD, log="y")
lines(dvalues, exponential, lwd = 2, col = “red”)
```

[image: Plot AB]

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code is fine.  Your problem is just that the exponential model is not an adequate model for the data, and the fit is rather poor.

Comment: How should i create an adequate model for the data? thanks

Comment: This is a REALLY big, broad, and important question.  I would start by consulting some applied statistics texts.  One of my favorites is:
http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://t3.gstatic.com/images%3Fq%3Dtbn:ANd9GcR4iXdgRwPe4WxrdQs5m9_Oo7uTvOOmcjyIPl7cq-UxzLpbfMPS&imgrefurl=http://books.google.com/books/about/Analysing_Ecological_Data.html?id%3DmmPvf-l7xFEC%26source%3Dkp_cover&h=1080&w=715&tbnid=jy0DFYk0GEwcQM:&tbnh=160&tbnw=106&usg=__8TnYOXUYdpNon3xruGeDyTKVG3E=&docid=HaS4dZhuIrceCM&itg=1